# How to add a column to the Profit and Loss Statement

Tags: account, odoo-15

How can i add a column to the profit and loss statement. Like after the amount column?

This is for odoo 15.

Comment: Please, provide a link to the Profit and Loss Statement

Comment: Hi, this is the link to the demo instance:
https://sasha.odoo.com/web?studio=app_creator#cids=1&menu_id=231&action=353

I need to add a column after the 2022 column

Comment: I couldn't access the database. Provide the link to the module or a minimum code (template id, report arch)

Comment: username: admin@gmail.com
password: admin

Comment: Odoo uses a client action to load the profit and loss report. Check the `account_report` action in javascript under the account module and look for the XML template defining the report content

Comment: Hi, can't seem to find the exact one for the profit and loss statement.